# When is the DoubleClick event raised other than for a double mouse click?

Tags: .net, winforms

[The documentation for the `MouseDoubleClick` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedoubleclick.aspx) states

> **Important**
>
> DoubleClick events are logically higher-level events of a control. They may be raised by other user actions, such as shortcut key combinations.

However, I have been unable to find a control that raises the `DoubleClick` event in situations in which `MouseDoubleClick` isn't also raised, and [the documentation for `DoubleClick` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doubleclick.aspx) doesn't mention anything either. When is this used?

Comment: Click is the more obvious one, you can click a button by pressing the space bar.  It is *allowed* for a control to call OnDoubleClick on any kind of input event, doesn't necessarily mean it makes sense to do so.

Comment: @HansPassant I know, pressing Enter is given as an example the `MouseClick` documentation. I can imagine some situations where `OnDoubleClick` would makes sense, one being pressing Enter in a `ListView`. However, in the ones I can come up with, it doesn't actually happen.

Comment: The standard .NET controls don't do this.  Can't speak for the tens of thousands other ones out there.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, that's helpful. (No sarcasm, even if it comes across that way.)

Answer (score 0):

Some cases you need mouse properties(location, clicks..), so you use mousedoubleclicks event, in others case you will not need them, so system can save some bytes and increase performance.

For example the Application below is almost pure GDI, so when i click some place it's so important that i have mouse properties...

[image]

**Update**

You are right in :

**1**: No case that doubleclick is raised and mousedoubleclick is not, neither vice-versa, because i decompiled the control class in .Net 3.5, and found the only place that tow events are raised is in the same place onmouseup with some conditions:

```
private void WmMouseUp(ref Message m, MouseButtons button, int clicks)
{
    try
    {
        int x = NativeMethods.Util.SignedLOWORD(m.LParam);
        int y = NativeMethods.Util.SignedHIWORD(m.LParam);
        Point p = new Point(x, y);
        p = this.PointToScreen(p);
        if (!this.GetStyle(ControlStyles.UserMouse))
        {
            this.DefWndProc(ref m);
        }
        else if (button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            this.SendMessage(0x7b, this.Handle, NativeMethods.Util.MAKELPARAM(p.X, p.Y));
        }
        bool flag = false;
        if ((((this.controlStyle & ControlStyles.StandardClick) == ControlStyles.StandardClick) && this.GetState(0x8000000)) && (!this.IsDisposed && (UnsafeNativeMethods.WindowFromPoint(p.X, p.Y) == this.Handle)))
        {
            flag = true;
        }
        if (flag && !this.ValidationCancelled)
        {
            if (!this.GetState(0x4000000))
            {
                this.OnClick(new MouseEventArgs(button, clicks, NativeMethods.Util.SignedLOWORD(m.LParam), NativeMethods.Util.SignedHIWORD(m.LParam), 0));
                this.OnMouseClick(new MouseEventArgs(button, clicks, NativeMethods.Util.SignedLOWORD(m.LParam), NativeMethods.Util.SignedHIWORD(m.LParam), 0));
            }
            else
            {
                this.OnDoubleClick(new MouseEventArgs(button, 2, NativeMethods.Util.SignedLOWORD(m.LParam), NativeMethods.Util.SignedHIWORD(m.LParam), 0));
                this.OnMouseDoubleClick(new MouseEventArgs(button, 2, NativeMethods.Util.SignedLOWORD(m.LParam), NativeMethods.Util.SignedHIWORD(m.LParam), 0));
            }
        }
        this.OnMouseUp(new MouseEventArgs(button, clicks, NativeMethods.Util.SignedLOWORD(m.LParam), NativeMethods.Util.SignedHIWORD(m.LParam), 0));
    }
    finally
    {
        this.SetState(0x4000000, false);
        this.SetState(0x8000000, false);
        this.SetState(0x10000000, false);
        this.CaptureInternal = false;
    }
}
```

**2**: The handler call is not called if no handler exists:

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
protected virtual void OnMouseDoubleClick(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MouseEventHandler handler = (MouseEventHandler) base.Events[EventMouseDoubleClick];
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not asking when to use which event. Besides, the `MouseEventArgs` class is instantiated even if no event handlers are registered for the corresponding event, so using one or the other saves exactly zero bytes in memory.

Comment: `MouseEventArgs` is already instantiated by the time that `OnMouseDoubleClick` is called. Furthermore, `OnDoubleClick` and `OnMouseDoubleClick` *are* called from other places, however, as far as I can tell, they are always both called.

Comment: Yes you're right, but meant the handler is not called... sorry my bad :)

Comment: I never claimed otherwise. Trying to call an event handler when no event handler is assigned causes a `NullReferenceException`, so no well-written class will try it.

Comment: +1 ... ok you got me, my 2 votes, my code and my search time... i give up :)